# Java - Default value of MaxPermSize - Sun JVM

Tags: java, jvm-arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default values for Xmx, Xms, MaxPermSize on non-server-class machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209450/default-values-for-xmx-xms-maxpermsize-on-non-server-class-machines)

We are using Sun JVM, and need to know the default value assigned to MaxPermSize

We are not passing any arguments to JVM

from this thread [Why is the default size of PermGen so small?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465067/why-is-the-default-size-of-permgen-so-small) I understand that it is 64MB.
Is it 64MB in all the cases or is it based on the system RAM size?

Comment: Which version of Sun (well, Oracle) JVM? I know for sure that it is still 64 MB for 1.6.x, no idea for more recent versions, regardless of the amount of RAM (x86_64, 32bit or 64bit JVMs).

Comment: @BrianRoach, the important thing I want to know is, if the value is dependent on the RAM size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not depend on the available RAM, but it does depend on:

- the version of the JVM that you're using -- older versions allocated less memory since computers had less RAM back then
- the architecture (64bit requires more than 32bit, so the default memory is also bigger)
- the actual OS configurations, since some operating systems might configure different defaults, although that's not actually the JVM that behaves differently

Answer (score 4):

You can find out the value of any HotSpot JVM flags / parameters by including `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` as a command line option.

The default values for many parameters depend on the JVM version, hardware/OS platform and/or physical memory size.

---

FWIW - on my machine the default value of MaxPermSize is `85983232` ... according to the above method.